{marginaleffects} Average plot with plot_predictions() for alle clusters of a multi level model
I want to display a plot that shows the predictions of a lme4 model over all clusters, but I just get a plot for the mode cluster
I have the following model and I want to know how "satislife" is changing (for females and males separatly) when "fem_parl_mean_diff" changes and all other predictors are kept at their mean.
mod5 <- lmer (satislife ~ 1 + gender * (fem_parl_mean + fem_parl_mean_diff + intdate_day  + poly(age, degree = 3) + GDP) + (1 + gender | country), data = merged_df)

I used marginaleffects::plot_predictions to get the corresponding plot
plot_predictions(mod5, condition = c("fem_parl_mean_diff", "gender"), newdata = datagrid(grid_type = "balanced"))

But this just gives me the plot of a specific country (mode). I also created a facet Plot with single plots for every country. What I want is a Plot showing the average results of this Facet Plot.
When using the by argument I get this Plot
Thanks for your Ideas!

Use the by argument instead of the condition argument. The difference is documented in the manual page:
?plot_predictions
There is also a lot of discussion and examples in this vignette: https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/plot.html
plot_predictions(mod5, 
   by = c("fem_parl_mean_diff", "gender")
) 

Edit: First make predictions for each group, then average them.
library(lme4)
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)

mod <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Sepal.Width + (1 | Species), data = iris)
pre <- predictions(mod, 
    by = "Petal.Length",
    newdata = datagrid(Species = unique, Petal.Length = seq(min(iris$Petal.Length), max(iris$Petal.Length), length.out = 100)))

ggplot(pre, aes(Petal.Length, estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = .2) +
    geom_line()


I have inserted the plot above that I am getting when using the by argument. What I'm looking for is an average plot of the facet plot (see also above).

I edited my answer with one potential solution.
